# How do I match the following with regex?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

```
Title1
......

Title2: Description
...................

Title3
......
```

I am trying to match `Title1`, `Description` and `Title3`. Using `(?<=: )(.*)(?=\n\.)`, I can match the `Description`. I couldn't figure how to match `Title1`, `Description` and `Title3` together.

Comment: Maybe `(?<=:\s|^).*(?=\n\.)` (=`(?:(?<=:\s)|(?=^)).*(?=\n\.)`) will do?

Comment: You could also optionally match the part with the semi colon `^[^:\r\n]+(?:: +\S.*)?(?=\n\.)`  See https://regex101.com/r/AW4lUN/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird

 That did not work. It also matches ```Title2: Description```.

Comment: Look at https://regex101.com/r/CzPcuz/1, matches what you asked for.

Comment: It is surprisingly not working for me in VS Code. But Thanks man.

Comment: Yes, there, `m` flag is on by default, you have to use `(?<=:\s|^(?<![\w\W])).*(?=\n\.)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VSCode, you can match the strings by finding the start of the whole file or the colon followed with a whitespace:

```js
(?<=:\s|^(?![^:\n]*:)).*(?=\n\.)
```

See the demo screenshot:

[image]

*Details*:

- `(?<=` - start of a positive lookbehind (that requires its pattern to match the text immediately to the left of the current location):

  - `:\s` - a colon and a whitespace
  - `|` - or
  - `^(?![^:\n]*:)` - start of the line that has no `:` after any zero or more chars other than `:` and line break chars
- `)` - end of the lookbehind
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?=\n\.)` - a positive lookahead that requires a line break and a `.` to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CzPcuz/4).

Comment: I am fairly new to regex. I know what this is ```^(?<![\w\W])``` but I didn't quite get it. Can you please elaborate? What do you mean by ```start of the whole file```?

Comment: @FrankShrestha `^` is a start of a whole string anchor in the regex world. When it is used with the `m` flag, or a `multiline` modifier, it starts matching start of the line position. In VSCode, the `m` flag is enabled by default, `^` matches any line start position. To make sure the `^` only matches file start, the first line start position, the `(?<![\w\W])` lookbehind makes sure there is no char before this position.

Answer (score 1):

You might also assert not a `:`  to the left, or assert that that string does not contain `:`  and then match the whole line.

```
(?<=: |^(?!.*?: )).*(?=\n\.)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert to the left

  - `:`  match `:`
  - `|` Or
  - `^(?!.*?: )` Negative lookahead, start of string and assert not `:`  in the line
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `.*` Match the whole line
- `(?=\n\.)` Assert a newline and `.`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4OqR1W/1)

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize I could use lookaround within a lookaround. Thanks.